# SQL Server CDC data transformation in source and publishing to messaging queue

Tags: sql-server, pipeline, change-data-capture

How can SQL Server CDC data be transformed from source and publish transformed payload to messaging queue. Since Debezium can do only SMT (simple message transformation). We need to join the change captured data with other source table and form a payload and publish to messaging queue like Kafka. What could be the suitable work around to solve this problem?

Comment: CDC data is not different from any other rowset other than having three special columns for metadata. Any ETL tool of your choice capable of executing arbitrary statements can select rows from the CDC tables using the `fn_cdc_get_[all/net]_changes` function and either remembering the LSNs processed or using time mapping functions. SO isn't the place for software recommendations, though.

Comment: i dont want to use cdc functions directly, i need to built a robust pipeline where change data should be allowed to get transformed by joining with another source table which should be able to push to an api or messaging queue

Comment: @Vishnu - rhetorically, how do you think something that would do what you describe would work if not by using the CDC functions that Jeroen mentioned?